# How to find logs for command terminated with exit code 137 error after kubectl exec command is triggered at pod

Tags: docker, namespaces, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

My pod is created and while executing below command in pod after sometime getting error as command terminated with exit code 137

```
kubectl exec gradlecommandfromcommandline -- ./gradlew gatlingRun- 
simulations.RuntimeParameters -DUSERS=500 -DRAMP_DURATION
=5 -DDURATION=30
```

How to debug the problem ,i mean what is the issue,mind you the same docker equivalent command runs fine with docker run,but issue is only after i execute kubectl exec command on pod,As i suspected memory issue in kubectl so i do specified memory limits within 'default' namespace using below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
name: mem-min-max-demo-lr
spec:
limits:
- max:
  memory: 1Gi
min:

  memory: 500Mi

type: Container
```

Comment: can you provide full 137 error you are facing?

Comment: https://support.nuodb.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003620366-Process-ended-with-exit-code-137 says exit code=137 means that either (1) something killed the container that hosted the TE or (2) something killed the process with SIGKILL (kill -9) (We can figure that out by taking the exit code and deduct 128 from it to get the actual signal number, i.e. 137-128=9). Check "Events" when you run kubectl describe <pod/name>

Comment: exit code 137 can mean the health check failed, as the pod will be automatically terminated if unhealthy. Another common cause is insufficient RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `kubectl exec` doesn't have a debug flag [1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec).

You could try to gather some logs with `kubectl logs gradlecommandfromcommandline`, additionally you could open a second session and check the container logs in `/var/log/` i.e. with `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log`

---

I would also recommend you to test decreasing your command parameters and test increasing the resources of the container.

Initially the exit code 137 means that the system terminated the container as it tried to use more **memory** than it's limit.